# How to create bins on a column in a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame df with structure like so:

**Input**

```
amount id
13000  1
30000  2
10000  3
5000   4
```

I want to create a new column which based on the quantiles of column 'amount'

**Expected Output:**

```
amount id amount_bin
13000  1  10000
30000  2  15000
10000  3  10000
5000   4  5000
```

Assume the qualities 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75 are 5000, 10000 and 15000 respectively

I know how to do this in R:

```
quantile <- quantile(df$amount, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0), na.rm = TRUE, 
                     names = FALSE)

df$amount_bin <- cut(df$amount, breaks = quantile, include.lowest = TRUE, 
                     labels = c(quantile[2], quantile[3], quantile[4], quantile[5]))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [QuantileDiscretizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer) from ML library.

Create buckets based on fitted quantiles:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.QuantileDiscretizer

val data = Array((13000, 1), (30000, 2), (10000, 3), (5000, 4))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("amount", "id")

val discretizer = new QuantileDiscretizer()
  .setInputCol("amount")
  .setOutputCol("result")
  .setNumBuckets(4)

val result = discretizer.fit(df).transform(df)
result.show()
```

Answer (score 17):

The QuantileDiscretizer works *ok* if your data is neatly distributed, however when you specify numBuckets **it does not split the range of values in a column into equally sized bins, but rather by some heuristic**. Nor are you able to select the boundaries of your bins.

The Bucketizer from Spark ML does have these features however:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer

val data = Array(0.99, 0.64, 0.39, 0.44, 0.15, 0.05, 0.30, 0.31, 0.22, 0.45, 0.52, 0.26)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data.map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("continuousFeature")

val bucketizer = new Bucketizer()
    .setInputCol("continuousFeature")
    .setOutputCol("discretizedFeature")
    .setSplits( Array(0.0, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.0 ) )

    // the array of split values are the binning boundaries

val binnedData = bucketizer.transform(df)

binnedData.show

+-----------------+------------------+
|continuousFeature|discretizedFeature|
+-----------------+------------------+
|             0.99|               9.0|
|             0.64|               6.0|
|             0.39|               3.0|
|             0.44|               4.0|
|             0.15|               1.0|
|             0.05|               0.0|
|              0.3|               3.0|
|             0.31|               3.0|
|             0.22|               2.0|
|             0.45|               4.0|
|             0.52|               5.0|
|             0.26|               2.0|
+-----------------+------------------+
```

Which I think is much nicer. Gives you a lot more control over your result.

Note that the range of your splits needs to contain all of the values in your input column, otherwise you will have to setup rules for handling invalid input values using the *setHandleInvalid* method.

You do not need to specify regularly spaced bins as I have in this example.

**Scaladoc**
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer

**Another example**
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/BucketizerExample.scala

Comment: This is nice.Can this be applied over Window function in spark ?